# Using Spack Containers for Local development using CLion

Tags: clion, spack

Spack is set up for the creation of containarize enviorments with all the dependencies.

This is great for github actions, but I will like to make it work for local development on CLion

Here is the [link](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/containers.html) to the spack containers

My main problem is that the non-standar installation of dependencies makes clion fail to find the files.

The container tries to make use of profile files, but since the terminal is  not interactive, CLion doesnt read them.

I have tried to set up the variables through ENV commands on Docker.

I have tried putting /opt/view on /usr/local, this one kind of works but ends up with messy requirments on the CMake files to index the .h files

I have tried manually settting the varaibles in CLion, this works, but with 150 configurations, having to do this manually seems like a terrible idea.

Has anyoen ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to make a Spack FS View (https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/environments.html#filesystem-views), this will install (trough symlinks) your spack packages in a give directory using the usual FS hierarchy (bin, usr, lib...). This will probably be easier for Clion to find.